# Why is my ANOVA returning negative F Values?

Tags: anova, nonlinear-regression, model-comparison

this is my first post here but I have benefited from reading all of your past conversations. I will try to make this question as clear as possible.

I'm trying to find if there are differences between the sensitivity of respiration to warming between elevations. I have accordingly specified the following non-linear models to describe each elevation separately ...

```r
model.high.location1 <- nls(value ~ a*exp(b*mean_temp_date),
                   data = highlocation1, start = list(a = 1, 
                    b = .1))

model.low.location1 <- nls(value ~ a*exp(b*mean_temp_date), 
                  data = lowlocation1, start = list(a = 1, 
                      b = .1))

model.high.location2 <- nls(value ~ a*exp(b*mean_temp_date),
                   data = highlocation2, start = list(a = 1, 
                      b = .1))

model.low.location2 <- nls(value ~ a*exp(b*mean_temp_date), 
                  data = lowlocation2, start = list(a = 1, 
                      b = .1))
```

These models give me parameter values just fine at all locations (different model for every location). For example ...

```r
 model.high.location1$m$getPars()
         a          b 
0.38669690 0.05699201 

 model.low.location1$m$getPars()
          a           b 
 2.25563007 -0.04508122
```

and

```r
 model.high.location2$m$getPars()
        a         b 
0.2393460 0.1583531 
 model.low.location2$m$getPars()
           a            b 
 5.818518258 -0.007246764
```

But when I compare the elevations using anova, sometimes I will get negative F-values.

```r
 anova(model.high.location1, model.low.location1)
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: value ~ a * exp(b * mean_temp_date)
Model 2: value ~ a * exp(b * mean_temp_date)
  Res.Df Res.Sum Sq  Df Sum Sq F value Pr(>F)
1     37    12.1379                          
2     54     8.6826 -17 3.4552 -0.6196      1
> #
```

And sometimes I won't.

```r
> anova(model.high.location2, model.low.location2)
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: value ~ a * exp(b * mean_temp_date)
Model 2: value ~ a * exp(b * mean_temp_date)
  Res.Df Res.Sum Sq Df  Sum Sq F value Pr(>F)
1      4     2.9937                          
2     11    23.6445 -7 -20.651  3.9418 0.1015
```

Could someone help me figure this out? I'm a comparative newbie so it might be something very simple, but I'd be thankful for any help at all.

Comment: You don't appear to be comparing nested models. What specific F test do you think you're doing?

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. At first I thought non-nested models were what I wanted as I just wanted to know if the parameters were significantly different from each other. But after searching along this line of inquiry it seems I should create a pooled dataframe including both elevations, and test my elevation separated models against this H0. To answer your question I expect the F test to be a ratio of the residual sum of squares between the models in question.